# How to distance word in navigation bar?

Tags: css

I am new in programming and I have a simple question: I want to make the words in this navigation bar be further from each other.

```js
    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }
    li{
        float: right;
        transform: translateX(-300px);
        transform: translateY(-30px;);
    }
    li a{
        display: block;
        text-align:center;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff ;
        font-size: 37px;
        font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
         <header class="title">CSS Tricks</header>
         <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
            
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>

              <li>  
                  <a href="#">About</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                  <a href="#">News</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point of using transform.. use `display: flex` instead of `float: right` and if you would like to have it on the right side, do `justify-content: flex-end`. About your question, if it is having space between the `<a>` use the `margin: 0 30px` or if your meant between letters, do `letter-spacing: 5px` like in the example below..

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo on this property `transform: translateY(-30px;);`

it should be without `;` after value -30px

`transform: translateY(-30px);`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you've got a padding of 16px on the sides of your hyperlink tags. Because it's on both the left and right sides, that adds up to 32px between the text of each. Increasing that value will increase the space between the links.

Adding padding or margin to the `<li>` elements would also work.